# Distinct on each group

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to group the data on License, Event, User, Course
and then only get one row per group.

Maybe there is some better way but following is my table

```
| License  | Course | Event | User |
|----------|--------|-------|------|
| L1       | C1     | E1    | U1   |
| L1       | C2     | E1    | U1   |
| L1       | C3     | E1    | U1   |
| L1       | C1     | E1    | U2   |
| L1       | C2     | E1    | U2   |
| L1       | C3     | E1    | U2   |
| L1       | C1     | E2    | U1   |
| L1       | C2     | E2    | U1   |
| L1       | C3     | E2    | U1   |
| L1       | C1     | E2    | U2   |
| L1       | C2     | E2    | U2   |
| L1       | C3     | E2    | U2   |
| L1       | C1     | E1    | U1   |
| L1       | C2     | E1    | U1   |
| L1       | C3     | E1    | U1   |
| L1       | C1     | E1    | U2   |
| L1       | C2     | E1    | U2   |
| L1       | C3     | E1    | U2   |
```

*And this is what I want*

```
| License  | Course | Event | User |
|----------|--------|-------|------|
| L1       | C1     | E1    | U1   |
| L1       | C1     | E1    | U2   |
| L1       | C1     | E2    | U1   |
| L1       | C1     | E2    | U2   |
| L1       | C1     | E1    | U1   |
| L1       | C1     | E1    | U2   |
```

thanks in advance

Comment: can you write on the question the code you tried and what was the problem?

Comment: only get one row per _what_ group?

Comment: you use MySQL 8 i hope? As on lower versions this is more tricky..

Comment: @aikaRawat:  Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: If you have no Primary Key, then you don't really have a table

Answer (score 0):

You can try `group by`

```
select * from yourtable group by License,Course,Event,User
```